# Ruby ENOENT error for curl statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Getting "No such file or directory (errno::ENOENT) error" for following statement 
result = %x[curl -k -w "%{http_code}" -m 3 -sL #{url} -o /dev/null]

What I understand that above statement should return the response code and which is not working here.
I don't have much knowledge on Ruby and Rails and encountered above during setting up my testing environment for cucumber.

Will some please help.

Comment: you might need to specify the absolute path to `curl` e.g `%x[/usr/bin/curl -k -w "%{http_code}" -m 3 -sL #{url} -o /dev/null]`, can you also confirm the error is related to what you posted

Comment: Yes, the error is related to the above post. It seems to be working after downloading the curl from following link https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/ and giving the absolute path.

Comment: BTW, is there any gem for curl.

Comment: you can use [`net/http`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) instead of a gem